# How can delete cookies form safari in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cookies, safari

I want to delete the cookies of iPhone's safari from my app in objective c. I am using following code

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray* instagramCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"api.instagram.com"]];

for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in instagramCookies) {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

But it can not be deleted. it is deleting only from cookies object, not safari cookies.
Because when again retrieve the cookies it again shows.

So Please help , how can delete cookies permanently from safari in iPhone SDK.